# How to select and deselect options if multiselect option coming from ajax response

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
    <div class="content-section">

        <form method="POST" id="moviesForm" ajax_load_cast="{% url 'ajax_load_cast' %}" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>
               <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="id_cast" class="col-form-label  requiredField">Cast<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="cast" value="" maxlength="50" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_cast"> 
                    <select id="add_cast2" multiple style="width:100%" ></select>
                   </div> 

                </div>
                <div id="" class="form-group">

                </div>

            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{% block js%}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var ajaxResult=[];
    $("#id_cast").keyup(function () {
      var url = $("#moviesForm").attr("ajax_load_cast");
      var text_input = $('#id_cast').val();

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
          'text_input': text_input
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $("#add_cast2").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
  </script>

{% endblock js%}
{% endblock content %}
```

I am implementing a django multiselect option formField with basic html and ajax request so that it filters results before showing all the results. But I don't know how to implement select and deselect with the ajax response that brings multiselect options from database. With each response it deselects the selected options.